# jQuery: How to identify which XHR handler ajaxComplete() was fired off for

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have multiple `$.get()` handlers in my JavaScript. I'd like to be able to run specific code when a handler has successfully finished its request. From jQuery's documentation, it looks like the following is what I'm looking for:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
});
```

The problem I have here is, this is going to get triggered for every `$.get()` handler. How can I identify which one it is going off for so I can take the correct steps that are required to update my user interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the xhr object and the settings object as an argument to the callback, you can use them to identify the ajax method

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, jqxhr, settings) {
    console.log(jqxhr)
    $(".log").text("Triggered ajaxComplete handler.");
});
```

But if you want to register a callback for a particular ajax request and you have access to that ajax request's promise object then you can use the .always() callback like

```
var promise = $.post('/echo/json/', {});//or $.ajax() etc
promise.always(function(){
    //do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I just wrap all jQuery AJAX methods in my own function. That way I can do all sorts of tracking and caching behaviors without relying on hooks. For example:

```
function AJAXLoad(method, data, callback) {
    var request = method + (new Date()).toString();
    console.log("Sending request " + request);
    $.ajax(method, { data: data, success: function(msg) {
        console.log("Request " + request + " completed.");
        callback(msg);
    }});
}
```